# Cannot invoke 'implode' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have to port an older Swift 1.2 project to Swift 2.1 and the project uses ExSwift extensively. unfortunately ExSwift hasn't been updated for Swift 2.1 (is it abandoned? Last update was six months ago).

I'm getting the above error with this piece of code:

```
public func * (array: [String], separator: String) -> String {
    return array.implode(separator)!
}
```

How can I fix it since array has no `implodeWithSeparator` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is provided by the

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == String {
    /// Interpose the `separator` between elements of `self`, then concatenate
    /// the result.  For example:
    ///
    ///     ["foo", "bar", "baz"].joinWithSeparator("-|-") // "foo-|-bar-|-baz"
    @warn_unused_result
    public func joinWithSeparator(separator: String) -> String
}
```

method:

```
public func * (array: [String], separator: String) -> String {
    return array.joinWithSeparator(separator)
}

let x = ["a", "b", "c"] * ","
print(x) // a,b,c
```